# MySQL Update command not working

Tags: php, mysql, ios, xcode

I have been trying to get mysql entries to update via php from iOS. However, xcode's simulator refuses to update the values. Did I format this correctly? (to clarify, database name is "login" and the two prog variables are integers (that doesn't have to be formatted differently does it?))

```
<?php
$prog= $_GET['prog'];
$prog1= $_GET['prog1'];
$dbh = new PDO('(censored)');
$sql = "UPDATE login SET oneam = $prog, twelvefif = $prog1 WHERE username = 'hello'"; 
$q = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$q;
?>
```

or in xcode...

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(censored)?prog=%@&prog1=%@", prog, prog1];
```

Comment: It depends what is stored in `$prog` , `$prog1`, `prog1`, `prog`

Comment: They are integers (1 and 0 only)

Comment: This is subject to SQL injection, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php#90209

Comment: you didn't pass `$login` to PHP side. Do you? (note: there is no problem in iOS side)

Comment: Ok, but I think that I should first learn to use the update command before adding that on

Comment: thanks shivan, but it did not solve the problem. I've updated the code to reflect the suggestions

Comment: try to echo the `$sql`, see if everything looks okay.

Comment: No errors...but no results...

Answer (score 0):

Change --

```
$prog= $_GET['prog'];
$login = "hello";
$prog= $_GET['prog1'];
```

To

```
$prog= $_GET['prog'];
$login = "hello";
$prog1= $_GET['prog1'];
```

Comment: Thanks, but that still didn't fix it

Answer (score 0):

You have to surrond your vars with single quotes for security, if the var has an integer no problem, but otherwise you have to use single quotes.

I know you are using prepared statements and that will handle this, but anyway you can try.

```
$sql = "UPDATE login SET oneam = '$prog', twelvefif = '$prog1' WHERE username = 'hello'";
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid sql injection problems, you should cast your variables to `int` or bind the variables in your prepared statement (preferred...):

```
$prog = (int) $_GET['prog'];
$prog1 = (int) $_GET['prog1'];
```

Apart from that you have to actually execute the prepared statement, just preparing it is not enough:

```
$q = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$q->execute();
```