# Update command not working for mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ios

I have been trying to get mysql entries to update via php from ios. I realize that I have made another question about update commands (see [MySQL Update command not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283501/mysql-update-command-not-working)) but this is a VERY different script that I am trying (and much simpler). However, I cannot get this to update either! What am I doing wrong? (ps. I have also tried this command with AND's instead of commas inbetween the sets and I have also tried $_POST...and I am connecting to my database). Also, I am just trying to figure out how to get the update command working...then I will learn how to sql inject. I have also tried manual values and still nothing.

```
<?php
$login = $_GET["log1b"];
$dogname = $_GET["dogname"];
$city = $_GET["city"];
$pass = $_GET["pass"];
$dogusername = $_GET["username"];
$mcode = $_GET["mcode"];

$con = mysql_connect("(censored)");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("(censored)", $con);
mysql_query("UPDATE login SET dogname = '$dogname', city = '$city', pass = '$pass', username = '$dogusername', mcode = '$mcode' WHERE login = '$login'");
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

or in xcode...

```
  NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://(censored)?username=%@&dogname=%@&mcode=%@&pass=%@&city%@&log1b=%@", fldUsername.text, flddogname.text, fldmcode.text, fldpass.text, fldcity.text, log1b];
```

Comment: You should check for a mysql error after the query. Also, you should be using $_GET not $_POST.

Comment: Try `echo mysql_error($con);` after the query and see what that gives you.

Comment: You're also missing a quote after `$city` and not escaping any parameters leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Actually Alex, my original script linked to this article was using PDO, but I couldn't get that update command to work either. You can view that under the "linked" category on the right. I tried to do something much simplier with this just to get it to work, but I couldn't get this to work either.

Comment: If so, could you do a select? just wondering on your db name of `(censored)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing a `'` around `$city`.

Also you may want to use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

The syntax looks good to me now. You should try to it manually (using something like [MySQL Toad](http://toadformysql.com/index.jspa)) to make sure the query is valid.

Comment: Ok. I've added the ' around city and changed all of them to $_GET, but still nothing...I've even echoed and nothing...

Comment: Are you sure it should be $_GET and not $_POST?

Comment: Chris, when do I use which? (I have tried both and they both fail, but I am just curious)

Comment: $_GET or $_POST is determined by the type of request you are making to the server. For example if you are using an HTML form and the “method” attribute is POST you can use $_POST to get your variables. Similarly if you are using AJAX via jQuery and you send $.ajax with “type” attribute equal to GET you can use $_GET.

Comment: On another note two (hopefully) helpful debug steps would be to echo/print your $_GET/$_POST variables and make sure they are reaching your PHP script okay, next echo out your query and run it in Toad or something like that to make sure it is valid. To me it looks like the syntax is okay but running it in Toad could tell you if there are other errors (wrong column names or table name for example).